# Button column in the middle of the text columns of datagridview of win forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview with 5 columns. 4 columns are generated from dataset and 5th is the edit column. In the 4th column I need to generate the buttons with text values of the dataset. Can anyone help me in this regard

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: I'm confused...
i tried to bind the dataset to grid and then struck with the button field...

Answer (score 0):

In the designer you can edit the columns by pressing the little Arrow in the right upper corner.

There add your button column and set the `DataPropertyName` to the name of the property you are trying to bind to. Leave the `UseColumnTextForButtonValue` on `False`.

See screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Good luck